# Extracting folder names from path

Tags: c#, path

I have a path like this

```
   Path =  C:\Users\cyberbemon\Documents\Development\Image tool\sources\AL001\2014-05-17\ImageTool\output.xml
```

I want to extract the folder names `2014-05-17` and `AL001` They will later be used as a filename 
for eg: `140517-AL001.xml`.

The problem is the paths are dynamic, so instead of `2014-05-17` and `AL001` I could have something different like `2012-05-17` and `AL401`. The one thing that remains the same is `ImageTool\output.xml`

So what's the C# equivalent of `GetParentof(GetParentof(\ImageTool\output.xml))`

When looking around I came across this `New DirectoryInfo(Path).Name` This for me returns ImageTool and that's no use to me.

Comment: What about the initial path `C:\Users\cyberbemon\Documents\Development\Image tool\sources\` will it remain same ?

Comment: Do you always have the "desiredValue1/desiredValue2/ImageTool/output.xml" ending?

Comment: `var first = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(path).FullName).Name;` and `var second = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(path).FullName).FullName).Name;`

Comment: @Habib No i doesn't, if someone else uses this tool and the data the path will be different

Comment: if you know the comun path, one way can help you is split by "\" and how you know the position of array so you can get the path you need like arraypath[x] , proib this !! i hope help you !!

Comment: @NahuelIanni Yes, that's always the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can guarantee that there are always 3 directory levels then

```
string p =  @"C:\Users\cyberbemon\Documents\Development\Image tool\sources\AL001\2014-05-17\ImageTool\output.xml";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(p);
string p1 = di.Parent.Parent.Name;
string p2 = di.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name;
```

The Parent property of a DirectoryInfo class is another DirectoryInfo, so it just a matter to place the appropriate number of recursive call to Parent

I should note that the `DirectoryInfo` class works also if you pass a file at its constructor. If you want to stick to the exact nature of the string then you could use the FileInfo class and recover the parent DirectoryInfo using:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(p);
string p1 = fi.Directory.Parent.Name;
```

Comment: `+1` Most elegant Steve very simple and readable example nice

Comment: +1 I was about to answer the question by using the Split method, was not aware of this one.

Comment: Beware of the Split method using the '\' char. It works only on Win OS. Use Path.DirectorySeparatorChar to be OS indipendent.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just split your string on the directory separator and navigate from the end of the array to the point you want.

```
        string[] pathParts = path.Split(new string[] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the string (not as elegant as using IO functions though):

```
string Path =  @"C:\Users\cyberbemon\Documents\Development\Image tool\sources\AL001\2014-05-17\ImageTool\output.xml";
string[] components = Path.Split('\\');
string p1 = components[components.Length - 2];
string p2 = components[components.Length - 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
    `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` to get directory from a file/directory.
In your case it would be

```
Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))))
```

But it would be more elegant to create a recursive method that take a path and a level in parameters and returns the Directory name.